# How do I refresh a Kendo UI combo box?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-combobox, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC Kendo UI combobox that is databound to a table with 1000's of records. I've set the MinLength property to 5 so I only return relevant results. The problem is, the user might need to change the text value all together. Is there a way to tell the control to refresh?

Here's the code for the control...

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(x => x.Product)
                    .Name("Product")
                    .DataTextField("Name") // Display value
                    .DataValueField("Id") //Return value
                    .MinLength(5)
                    .AutoBind(false)
                    .Suggest(true)
                    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("Products", "Home").Data("onGetProducts");
                        });
                    })
                )
```

Comment: under what circumstance do you want it to refresh? On a timer, or are you feeding it an event that it could hook onto?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if I understand what you are struggling with:
simply call read action again from where ever you need:

```
$("#Product").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think with wrapper you cannot refresh but the better way for get result is [Kendo](http://www.kendoui.com/forums.aspx) froum
and u can use this [question](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/combobox/can-t-refresh-reload-data-combobox.aspx):

As it is stated in the docs, the [refresh](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#refresh) method of the widget does not [reload](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#read) the data of the DataSource. To reload the data use the read method of the dataSource.

Comment: that's a good example but I can't figure out how to get the control to call refresh. In this example the user has to manually press refresh.